# Displaying an error message for System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix-2

I have tried to catch my HttpExceptions using a try catch block in my *_PageStart.cshtml* file using [this site as a reference](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior) but that didn't seem to work. Does anyone else have a solution for setting a max filesize error message? I do not wish to simply increase my upload limit in web.config because users of my site shouldn't need to be uploading files larger than 10MB, so that is my upload limit. I have also tried handling it with my global.asax file but that didn't work.

Surely, there must be a way to redirect to another page or to simply display an error message upon receiving a file which exceeds the request limit.

Comment: follow these steps for showing custom error messages for different http errors http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

Comment: Sorry but those steps are for MVC, I need a solution for ASP.NET web pages aka webmatrix

Comment: thats why I just made a comment, wasn't sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix this myself by using the event handler in Global.asax